Get .jks file from Google Play Console .der file for EAS
I am having issues with the Android side of this new app I am due to release.
I am using EAS to build my app, I already created all the necessary keystore information, and uploaded my .jks file to EAS, created my OAuth 2.0 keys in Google Cloud Console, but when I downloaded my app in the internal testing environment, the Google SSO was not working, and I am sure it is to do with the SHA-1 fingerprint.
I noticed that in the App Signing section in Google Play Console, the Upload key certificate has a different fingerprint, which is the one I assume I need to use.
I cannot request a rest key, as the option is blocked. So I thought I could just download the one there, and use that in EAS and my Google Cloud Console.
I have followed a bunch of different things, but the .der file Google gives, doesn't have any private key, which the terminal is telling me I need.
Some other source told me to generate a new private key, convert the .der to a .pem and combine that with the private key to get my .jks file, but when I uploaded that to EAS the SHA-1 was different to the one in the Google Play Console, what am I actually supposed to do?
EDIT
I found this link
https://forums.expo.dev/t/how-to-import-google-play-console-certificate-from-an-existing-android-app-into-eas-credentials/70906
This allowed me to generate the .jks with the correct SHA-1, but now, if I try to build Android with EAS, I get the error:
Error: The alias specified for this keystore does not exist. Make sure you specified the correct value.
I uploaded the .jks to the credentials on EAS, I added the alias, and the passwords, so now I am really not sure what is going wrong.
